# Using iw to add a virtual wireless interface, getting the error "No such device (-19)"

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, debian

I am trying to add a virtual wireless interface to my debian squeeze system using iw.

The output of iw list is shown below:

```
root@alix:~# iw list
Wiphy phy0
```

I am using the command:

```
iw dev phy0 interface add wlan1 type station
```

to add the virtual interface wlan1 however this gives me the error:

```
command failed: No such device (-19)
```

If I use the command:

```
iw dev wlan0 interface add wlan1 type station
```

it passes fine however if I try use both wlan0 and wlan1 I get an error saying neither are unique and so that doesn't work for me.

Anyone any ideas what could be causing this? 
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

About the first error you get ("command failed: No such device (-19)"): You can either use

```
iw phy phy0 interface add <name> type <type>
```

or

```
iw dev wlan0 interface add <name> type <type>
```

As long as the physical names and the device names don't clash, you can also omit the phy/dev keywords and simply use

```
iw phy0 interface add <name> type <type>
```

---

About using both interfaces at the same time and the message about them not being unique:
This is probably because they both use the same MAC address. You can try to change the MAC address of the new interface before activating it.

```
ip link set dev <dev-name> address <new-mac-address>
```

---

A word about your interface modes:
My iw command (v3.4) says

> Valid interface types are: managed, ibss, monitor, mesh, wds.

Not sure what "station" will do.

Also, if you're trying to operate the two interfaces in different modes, make sure your wlan card supports this:

```
iw list
[...]
Supported interface modes:
     * IBSS
     * managed
     * AP
     * AP/VLAN
     * WDS
     * monitor
     * mesh point
software interface modes (can always be added):
     * AP/VLAN
     * monitor
interface combinations are not supported
```

Notice the last line.

Comment: `type station` will work just fine, as would do `type mgd`. Would be a shame to not accept `station`, since the kernel constant is named `NL80211_IFTYPE_STATION`.